# Azure function App with ASB - how maxConcurrentCalls works

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

I wondering how "maxConcurrentCalls" setting works for Azure Service Bus (ASB) triggered Azure function(AF).
I have an "azure function" App with only 1 AF in it. To handle load scenarios "Max Instance count" set to 5. Which means I can have 5 instance of my Azure running to handle increased load. But I have noticed that there is a setting "maxConcurrentCall" available.

Does Setting this to(say) 5, means my single instance will pick 5 message from the queue and execute them in Parallel? What is the default value of this setting?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The maxConcurrentCalls setting determines how many messages an Azure Function can handle at the same time when triggered by Azure Service Bus.
2. default value of maxConcurrentCalls is 16 if you don't change it.
3. You can adjust maxConcurrentCalls based on your needs to control how many messages can be processed at the same time by the function.

Comment: You mean single instance will process 16 message and if available message count goes beyond 16 then it will fork a new instance of AF, right? also in my case hosting plan is "dedicated", hope you have factored in this also.

Comment: Yes, that's correct! If you have a single instance of the Azure Function with maxConcurrentCalls set to 16  it means that this instance can process up to 16 messages concurrently.

Comment: Is it applicable for Dedicated plan also?

Comment: yes it is applicable

Comment: can you share some link to this info?

Comment: Confirming that Syed's answer is correct.   The setting controls concurrency per scaled 
 instance of the function.   Documentation can be found here:   https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp